# Custom Ruby gem is not loading with bundler

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm creating a custom gem (`sample_gem`) and I want to use it inside one of my sample Rails app and see how it works. In my gem version is 0.0.1 (default)

So What I did so far is,

1. created a rails4 project - `sample project`
2. clone the gem source to `vendor/sample_gem`
3. in the the `sample_project` gem file added

   gem 'active_console', '0.0.1', path: './vendor/active_console'

but when I run `bundle install` I'm getting the following error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'sample_gem (= 0.0.1) ruby' in source at ./vendor/sample_gem.
Source does not contain any versions of 'sample_gem (= 0.0.1) ruby'
```

I searched the web and for several gems, but seems like I couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: Is `active_console` or `sample_gem` the name of the gem?

Comment: I update my answer. I think with that works on Rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do fix thine sequence with the following:

Let's assume that `sample_gem` custom gem is resided in the **/home/user/git/sample_gem** folder, and `bundler` is already installed.

1. Create a rails project;
2. Add to its **Gemfile** the following line:

   ```
    gem 'sample_gem', path => '/home/user/git/sample_gem'
   ```
3. Issue bundling with:

   ```
    $ bundle install
   ```

NOTE: If thine `sample_gem` gem requires `active_console` gem, the last shell be specified in the **Gemfile** of the `sample_gem` gem.

Comment: thanks its finally working. 'active console' is the actual gem name ;). I used `sample_gem` as just to make the things simpler

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.

1. Puts the gem's folder in the root directory of your application
2. Call your gem in the Gemfile normally like `sample_gem`
3. Bundle install

This works right now in my Rails 4 app.

Comment: Thanks @skozz for your answer. After some changes in my samplegem.gemspec I got it working under vendor folder, which is my preferred way. But thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had to `rvm implode` and re-install rvm/rubies for this to work...